# How to override spring.mail properties in spring boot application during runtime?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application which sends emails depending on some configuration given by the user.
Therefore I have defined the host and the port of the default smtp server in my `application.properies`

```
spring.mail.host=127.0.0.1
spring.mail.port=1025
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=15000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=13000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=15000
```

Actually I am sending like this

```
@Service("EmailService")
public class EmailServiceImpl implements IEmailService {
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
 public EmailServiceImpl(JavaMailSender emailSender) {
        this.mailSender = emailSender;
    }

public boolean sendWithAttachment(IMailConfig aMailConfig, MimeMessageHelper aMimeMessageHelper) {
        try {
            LOG.debug("sending email with attachment");
            String[] toReceivers = aMailConfig.getReceiver().stream()
                .map(n -> n.getReceiver())
                .toArray(String[]::new);

            aMimeMessageHelper.setTo(toReceivers);
            aMimeMessageHelper.setSubject(aMailConfig.getSubject().getSubject());
            aMimeMessageHelper.setText(aMailConfig.getMessage().getText(), aMailConfig.getMessage().isHtml());
            aMimeMessageHelper.setFrom(aMailConfig.getFrom().getReceiver());

            aMimeMessageHelper.addAttachment(aMailConfig.getInstancePdf().getName(), aMailConfig.getInstancePdf().getPdfPath().toFile());
            mailSender.send(aMimeMessageHelper.getMimeMessage());
            
            LOG.debug("email sent");
            return true;

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            LOG.error("error while sending email, error with the mime message {0}", e);

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            LOG.error("error while sending email: {0}", e1);
        }


        return false;
    }
```

Now I want to allow that this will be overriden by the customer during runtime. So how can I achieve this. Currently I have already the information for from the customer e.g.

New mailserver should be `foobar.for.testing` and the port `25`, is there a way to set the host and the port of JavaMailSender? Something like this

```
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
  mailSender.setUsername(emailUsername);
  mailSender.setPassword(emailPassword);
  mailSender.setHost(emailHost);
  mailSender.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Well the documentation explains quite well how to do that. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config

Comment: @M.Deinum Thansk, but the documentation shows more how to load different property files or to reload them, but I want to override a property on the fly. Just added more information in my question, maybe this makes it clearer.

Comment: You cannot, as the bean is a singleton and initialized at startup. Changing it on the fly would change it for everyone. You stated runtime not on the fly in your question.

Comment: @M.Deinmum Do you know how I can achieve it to load these settings from my own property file and with my own prefix? I saw that the MailProperties class handles this  is it possible to extend this class so that a different prefx will be used. Then I need to "tell" springboot  to use my extended MailProperties. Any adivce? thanks

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vahidhedayati/69f61e99e5e1bc03f92b8cf263ef6f8a Take a look here I found a hackish way of changing config on the fly, as a configuration file coniguration is picked up when app is started